# What hydration system should I use for multiple activities?

Tags: water

Looking for a hydration pack that I can use for riding, running, snowboarding and (by removing the bladder and putting it into my travel pack) backpacking across Europe.

My requirements are pretty simple:

- Small
- 2L capacity (or around that mark)
- Light
- Minimal - no extra storage or other bells and whistles are necessary
- Reasonably strong/good quality

What do you recommend?

At this stage I'm interested in [this](http://www.deuter.com/en_US/backpack-details.php?category=127&id=1700&title=Hydro%20lite%202.0) bag by Deuter.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that bag.  Buy it. Try it. Don't like it, return it.

Comment: Seems like Deuter is among the top brands along with Camelbak. Check out this round-up, http://www.galttech.com/research/sports/best-hydration-pack.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with a [Viper 4 by Osprey](http://www.ospreypacks.com/en/product/mens_1_1/viper_4), which is quite small (only enough extra room for keys/phone, and to attach helmet on the outside). It comes with the [best bladder/hose/bite valve system](http://www.ospreypacks.com/en/product/mens_1_1/hydraform_reservoir_1) I've seen. Got it on special at [Paddy Pallin](http://www.paddypallin.com.au/) in Melbourne for $70.

Answer (score 2):

I find Camelbak (http://www.camelbak.com/Sports-Recreation/Packs.aspx) very simple and elegant, and from my own experience after using Camelbak in military activity for a couple of years now I can absolutely recommend it.

Example for your requirements: http://www.camelbak.com/Sports-Recreation/Packs/2011-Classic-3L-Intl-Only.aspx even though it is for 3 litres.

I don't know Deuter from your link and can't say what's best.